# Non-resolvable import POM Failure to find

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependency-management

I experimented with spring boot like module in parent pom and now I get error

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.0.0.M6 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 30, column 19
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project mydomain.project:main-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\gitProjects\main-server\sources\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.0.0.M6 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 30, column 19 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I tried delete myproject in `.m2` local repo

I have maven project with 2 modules(simple java and spring boot). I extract parent from spring boot to main pom like dependensyManagment and set paren to spring boot - main project. After that I get this error

I revert changes and all works fine. The step by step I faunt point when all crush

1. I add this to main pom

> ```
> <dependencyManagement>
>     <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
>         <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
>         <type>pom</type>
>         <scope>import</scope>
>       </dependency>
>     </dependencies>   </dependencyManagement>
> ```

2. in spring boot I change this

> ```
> <parent>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>       <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
>       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
>   </parent>
> ```

to this:

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>main-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>main.project</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -U clean compile`? This forces a re-check for the dependencies.

Comment: please clear your question.. and update it by some of the content of pom.xml. Where is line 30 and column 19. We won't be able to identify the problem.

Comment: @Florian Albrecht Yes I tried - not helped

Comment: try to delete the local repo under m2, what's under org/spring directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version 2.0.0.M6 isn't located in the repo http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. If you wan't to use this version you have to use the maven repo http://repo.spring.io/milestone. So add it to your POM file:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone-repo</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I would recommend you to use the latest release version of spring-boot (1.5.8.RELEASE), not a milestone version. I don't know how your POM looks like, but you can define spring boot in your POM in different ways:

## 1. Using the Spring Boot parent POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Then you can add the dependencies you wish to use e.g.:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

See: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

## 2. Declare Spring-Boot in Dependency-Management

If you already using an own parent POM, you could also import the spring boot dependency management in your POM:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Same as in variant #1 you can declare afterwards the dependencies of spring boot you wish to use.

Comment: that's why I have a mistake. if I do so. how to solve it?

Comment: have you tried to use the latest release version 1.5.8.RELEASE? How did you import spring boot? With the parent pom declaration in your pom?

Comment: Yes work. I was thinking of trying it. but what about the version 2.0.0.M6

Comment: The version 2.0.0.M6 isn't located in the repo https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. If you wan't to use this version you have to use the maven repo http://repo.spring.io/milestone/

Comment: @P.VAN I think you should explain how to add a repository to a POM (just add it to your example).

Comment: Why not install the version of `spring-boot-starter-web`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you didn't add spring boot dependency having already spring-boot as parent. That was my case.